# Where is `*` documented in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, multiplication

I don't find where `*` is documented. It seems that it can be equivalent to either `tf.multiply` or `tf.scalar_mul`. Is it so?

Answer (score 5):

The most reliable documentation is the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L1127):

```py
def _mul_dispatch(x, y, name=None):
  """Dispatches cwise mul for "Dense*Dense" and "Dense*Sparse"."""
  is_tensor_y = isinstance(y, ops.Tensor)
  if is_tensor_y:
    return gen_math_ops._mul(x, y, name=name)
  else:
    assert isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor)  # Case: Dense * Sparse.
    new_vals = gen_sparse_ops.sparse_dense_cwise_mul(y.indices, y.values,
                                                     y.dense_shape, x, name)
    return sparse_tensor.SparseTensor(y.indices, new_vals, y.dense_shape)

...

_OverrideBinaryOperatorHelper(_mul_dispatch, "mul")
```

This means `__mul__` operator overload, which does `_mul_dispatch`. As you can see, it calls either `gen_math_ops._mul` (which is the under-the-hood core function of [`tf.multiply`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply)) or `sparse_dense_cwise_mul` if the tensor is sparse.

By the way, `tf.scalar_mul` is just a wrapper over `scalar * x` ([source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L501)), so it's basically the same thing, but the dependency is the other way around.

Comment: reading source code to work out how something works may result in mistaking implementation for contract