# what is the difference between `tf.multiply` and `*`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After `import tensorflow.kera.backend as K`

**what is the difference between `tf.multiply` and `*`?**

**Similarly, What is the difference between `K.pow(x, -1)` and `1/x`??**

I write the following codes of a customized metrics function based on some other's codes.

```
def dice_coef_weight_sub(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    Returns the product of dice coefficient for each class
    """
    y_true_f = (Lambda(lambda y_true: y_true[:, :, :, :, 0:])(y_true))
    y_pred_f = (Lambda(lambda y_pred: y_pred[:, :, :, :, 0:])(y_pred))

    product = tf.multiply([y_true_f, y_pred_f]) # multiply should be import from tf or tf.math

    red_y_true = K.sum(y_true_f, axis=[0, 1, 2, 3]) # shape [None, nb_class]
    red_y_pred = K.sum(y_pred_f, axis=[0, 1, 2, 3])
    red_product = K.sum(product, axis=[0, 1, 2, 3])

    smooth = 0.001
    dices = (2. * red_product + smooth) / (red_y_true + red_y_pred + smooth)

    ratio = red_y_true / (K.sum(red_y_true) + smooth)
    ratio = 1.0 - ratio
    # ratio =  K.pow(ratio + smooth, -1.0) # different method to get ratio

    return K.sum(multiply([dices, ratio]))
```

In the codes, can I replace `tf.multiply` by `*`? Can I replace `K.pow(x,-1)` by `1/x`??

(From tensorflow's document, I know the difference between `tf.pow` and `K.pow`: `tf.pow(x,y)` receives 2 tensors to compute x^y for corresponding elements in `x` and `y`, while `K.pow(x,a)` receives a tensor `x` and a integer `a` to compute x^a. But I do not know why in the above code `K.pow` receives a float number 1.0 and it still works norally)

Comment: AFAIK, .* is notation for element-wise multiplication, similar to matlab, I don't know about `/`

Comment: Python does not have a .*, here it is just 2. (as 2.0) multiplied with red_product

Comment: And I don't get this question: Can I replace K.pow by / ??, / is the division operator, what does pow have to do with it?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  Is K.pow(x, -1) equal with 1/x?

Comment: Yeah thats a math property

Comment: So is tf.multiply  can also be replaced by * ?

Comment: Yes, you can do those replacements.

Comment: The answer to that question is already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746646/where-is-documented-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the two operands of `*` are both `tf.Tensor`s and not `tf.sparse.SparseTensor`s , the `*` operator is the same as `tf.multiply`, i.e., elementwise multiplication with broadcasting support.

If you are interested in studying the source code that performs the operator overloading, the key parts are:

1. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L891
2. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L1225
3. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L1201

For `tf.sparse.SparseTensor`s, `*` is overloaded with sparse tensor-specific multiplication ops.

Assuming you're using Python3, the `/` operator is overloaded to the `tf.math.truediv` (i.e., floating-point division, which corresponds to the `RealDiv` op of TensorFlow).

In Python2, the `/` operator may be doing integer division, in which case it's overloaded in a dtype-dependent way. For floating dtypes, it's `tf.math.truediv`, for integer dtypes, it's `tf.math.floordiv` (integer floor division).

`tf.pow()` uses a different operator (i.e., the `Pow`) operator. But assuming all your dtypes are floating-point, `1 / x` and `tf.pow(x, -1.0)` should be equivalent.